# Is "Artists are other than politicians played their own roles of cultural critics." a correct sentence?

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence correct grammatically?

> Artists are other than politicians played their own roles of cultural critics.

I found it [here](http://ptebible.blogspot.com/2017/05/latest-write-from-dictation-after-may.html) and I think it should be transliterated incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a way to parse this sentence, even by adding commas in various places. As far as I can see it is not grammatical.

What is the subjects of **played**? Why do we have present tense **are** and past **played**?

> Artists are other than politicians

makes some kind of sense in isolation. Either of

> Artists played their own roles of cultural critics

and

> Politicians played their own roles of cultural critics

would also make sense, but running the two together does not work, we don't know the subject of played. We could use **who** to clarify that we mean **politicians**.

> Artists have a different nature from politicians, who played their own roles of cultural critics.

But I would rewrite the sentence, pulling out the separate parts of the argument:

> One of the roles of an artist is be a critic of culture. This may have some similarity with the actions of politicians, but artists are other than politicians. Politicians play their own roles of cultural critics.